# How to get text which is on top of a image in android?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have a image with text on top of it. I need to extract the text from the image.

For example: Consider i have a image and on top of the image i have a LOGO "*NOKIA*". I would like to extract the logo as a text from the image.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean get text from imageview. I assume you want to extract text on a image in android. To do that you require a OCR- Optical Character recognizer.

I suggest have look at this link [Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr).

Also download this and modify the same according to your needs. https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR.

[Android OCR using tess-two a fork of tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525004/android-ocr-using-tess-two-a-fork-of-tesseract).

https://github.com/smart-mobile-software/ocrapiservice.

Comment: hi @Raghunandan Am asking that ...i have an `ImageView` in that image i have some text.For example:i have logo of the nokia,from that logo i have to get the "NOKIA" to `TextView` ..this is my doubt is this possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use any open source OCR libraries to achieve your goal. try the links above.

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan ... It will helpful for me !

Answer (score 0):

It's an image. so you can try android OCR.

https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

http://code.google.com/p/mobileocr/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk